# Java Class - main not compiling when i read to departments

Tags: java, algorithm, class

I wrote the two departments and when I try to read to the class from the chief and I have a problem compiling and I can not understand what the problem is, I'd love to help.

in main the error is on the line : 5.

**Main:**

```
 public class main {
public static void main(String[]args){
    Lecturer LecturerObject = new Lecturer("Dani",3,"Banana",1001);

    The error is here >>Lecturer[] L1 = new Lecturer("Dani",2,"Banana",1001);

College FirstCollege = new College("Hmpson",2, L1);
}
 }
```

**First Class:**

```
 public class Lecturer {
public String nameOfLecturer = "";
public int numOfTimesPenFalls = 0;
public  String favoriteIceCream = "";
public int numAuto = 1000;

//constructors, same name like class
public Lecturer(String name, int TimesPenFalls, String IceCream,
        int num) {
    nameOfLecturer = name;
    numOfTimesPenFalls = TimesPenFalls;
    favoriteIceCream = IceCream;
    numAuto = num;
    int maxLecturer=10;
}

//Copy constructor 
public Lecturer(Lecturer other){
    nameOfLecturer = other.nameOfLecturer;
    numOfTimesPenFalls = other.numOfTimesPenFalls;
    favoriteIceCream = other.favoriteIceCream;
    numAuto = other.numAuto;
}
 }
```

**Secoand Class:**

```
public class College {
public String CollegeName = "";
public int numOfLecturers = 0;
public Lecturer[] allLecturers;

// constructors, same name like class
public College(String name, int numLecturers, Lecturer[] dataBase) {
    CollegeName = name;
    numOfLecturers = numLecturers;
    allLecturers = dataBase;
    int maxLecturer = 10;
}

// getter, only private
public String getCollegeName() {
    return CollegeName;
}

// setter, only private
public void setCollegeName(String newcollegeName) {
    CollegeName = newcollegeName;
}

public boolean newLecturer(Lecturer addNewLecturer, int maxLecturer) {
    if (numOfLecturers < maxLecturer || numOfLecturers == maxLecturer) {
        numOfLecturers += 1;
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.print("Sorry, Max Lecturer!");
        return false;
    }
}

public void sortLecturer(Lecturer[] arrAllLecturers) {
      int numOfTimesPenFalls = 0;

    }

}
```

I'm first started with java I would be happy for a detailed explanation where is the problem, thank you very much.

Comment: You are trying to assign a `Lecturer` object, to an array of  `Lecturer` : `Lecturer[] L1 = new Lecturer("Dani",2,"Banana",1001);`

Answer (score 2):

This statement here

`Lecturer[] L1 = new Lecturer("Dani",2,"Banana",1001);` is wrong because you have defined **L1** as an array but you are initializing it as a simple Object....

in some IDEs like eclipse, the compiler will complain with a message like

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Lecturer to Lecturer[]

Ergo: you need to init L1 as it is, as an array:

do this:

```
Lecturer[] L1 = new Lecturer[]{new Lecturer("Dani",2,"Banana",1001)};
```

now you have an array with one Lecturer object inside..

Comment: You forgot the `new` Lecturer[]{..}

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign array Lecture object to array, which can be done in following manner correctly.

```
Lecturer[] L1 = new Lecturer[] {new Lecturer("Dani",2,"Banana",1001)};
```

Comment: thank you.Now the department College gets all the parameters that in the Department Lecturer?
That means when I create a new college I want it to create a new Lecturer with all the parameters to be inside.

In college class, I added a method that adds an additional lecturer (NewLecturer) Is it written correctly?